# Removing an array element from MongoDB collection does not work

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this data

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("575e66a4c2b503944800002b"),
   "phone": "201-780-8497",
   "orders": [
     "1961682636",
     "43243242" 
  ] 
}
```

I want to remove `order` '43243242' where `phone` is "201-780-8497"

Here is my PHP code

```
$collection->update(
        array('phone'=>$doc['phone']),
        array('$pull' => array('orders' => array('1961682636'), array('safe' => TRUE))
));
```

This does nothing, no error, no exception.

Where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You update operation should be :

```
db.collection.update(
    { "phone" : "201-780-8497" },
    { "$pull": { "orders": "43243242" } }
)
```

and your PHP code:

```
$collection->update(
    array('phone' => '201-780-8497'),
    array('$pull' => array('orders' => '43243242'))
);
```

You are getting it wrong on the **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)** syntax; you don't need to push the element you want to remove to an array as the **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)** document, just reference the value. For a more detailed explanation, consult the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).